# The same user listed twice with different reputation/badges in Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

I am sure this will disappear soon, but I have just gone to Area 51, Mathematics, and this is what I saw:

[image]

The user Akhil is listed twice, and he has different reputation/badges in each instance! Is this a bug that can be fixed, that is, is this something that might happen again with other proposals/users and should be checked out?

By the way, the link to the mathematics proposal is [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3355/mathematics), but as I said, the duplicate might disappear soon.

ADDED: When you click on the [first profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/536/akhil-mathew), you get his math.stackexchange profile, but when you click on the [second profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/109/akhil-mathew), you get a "page not found". mmmm...

Comment: I tagged it `support`, because I assume that he has two accounts, which should be merged.

Comment: @Ladybug, and how would his two distinct accounts own the same questions?

Comment: @badp, looks like they are already merged. But it's not handled correctly. So yes, it is a bug.

Comment: @Ladybug: I can still see it there....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed now. User accounts no longer show up in "Top Users" once they have been removed.